# $_REQUEST and setcookie Deprecated

Tags: php, request, deprecated, setcookie

Please help me with this issue.
I have a script and for the admin area it requests a file "login.php" with the following code:

```
<?
if($_COOKIE["ok"]==1){
    setcookie("user",$_REQUEST["name_theuser"]);
    setcookie("tipe",$_REQUEST["thetipe"]);
}else{
    echo "<script>document.location.href='disconnect.php';</script>";
}
echo "<script>document.location.href='bord.php';</script>";

?>
```

As I understand from my little knowledge and search there are deprecated in php 5.3.x

The symptom is that with the correct user and password it will not login, it doesn't redirect properly.

If anyone could land a hand it will be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Neither of those is deprecated, but both of those are a bad idea for authentication — this sort of looks like authentication. Anyways, why not use a `Location` header to not depend on JavaScript for redirection?

Comment: Do you have any error messages. Did you look to error.log?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your JavaScript redirect is wrong. You have `document.location` it should be `window.location`. `$_REQUEST` is not depreciated, but you do have to make sure you are using it correctly. If your form is being submitted, make sure you test for your submit button being set. Really your code should look more like this, if you are using the `$_POST` method, which is more secure:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submitButton']) && isset($_COOKIE['ok']) && $_COOKIE['ok'] === '1'){
  setcookie('user', $_POST['name_theuser']);
  setcookie('tipe', $_POST['thetipe']);
  //send a header or do your thing here
}
else{
  header('LOCATION:disconnect.php'); die();
}
?>
```

I was also unclear why you were trying to do a redirect, no matter what, at the bottom of your page.

Side Note:

You do not have to use `window.location.href =`. You can actually just use `window.location =` as a shortcut. Shorter yet, you can actually just use `location =`, because `window` is implicit.

Comment: Thank you for all the help and support given.

Comment: I gave this a -1 because this answer is not 100% accurate. `window.location.href` is accurate. The use of output buffering to avoid possible accidental output (are you expecting warnings?) is _smelly_ at best. The Location header is capitalized, which is non-standard (but accepted). A script redirect is not equivalent to a header redirect, I'll agree a header redirect is probably what is desired here, but it's not equivalent (answer doesn't mention this). Poor explanation of the nature of `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes I forget how inadequate my answers are. Perfection is always important.

Answer (score 0):

`setcookie` and `$_REQUEST` are **not** deprecated. Check: http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php

Depending on your server configuration `$_REQUEST` may not be available, which is probably what is going on here. This is also the preferred configuration because `$_REQUEST` is perceived to be bad.

`$_REQUEST` is the combined input of `$_GET` and `$_POST`. The fix is to replace it with the correct one.

If you're coming from a form with `action="post"` your input is in `$_POST`. If you're coming in on a url like `mysite/login.php?name_theuser=john&thetipe=foo` then you'll find your input in `$_GET`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will try to get the bottom of it. Its pointing like in your example "mysite/login.php?name_theuser=john&thetipe=foo". My code knowledge is quite small. Thank you again!